# Will i still be able to run my iOS 8.0 app on my iPhone 6 with iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I am a developer and i am thinking about updating my iPhone (8.4) to iOS 9 beta. I know all the pros and cons but i was wondering if, if i were to update to iOS 9, it would still be possible to run my app ( was created in Xcode 6.4, deployment target 8.0) on my iPhone using Xcode 7 beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can run it with Xcode 7 beta on your iOS 9 device (but not Xcode 6). But you **can't** submit to App Store with Xcode beta until it's out of beta, so I recommend not taking any Xcode 7/iOS 9-only approaches for backwards compatibility if you want to submit within the next two months.

Comment: I am currently using iOS 8.4 beta and Xcode 6.4 beta. To upload my builds to the App Store i use Xcode 6.3 final.
So, if i use Xcode 7 to get the app running on my iPhone, i can still use Xcode 6.3 to upload the build, right?

Comment: Not sure on this. I have an iPhone on iOS 9. I was able to deploy my app from Xcode 6 and debug fine. Maybe they changed that this year...

Comment: Yes, you can still use Xcode 6 to submit your app against the iOS 8 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I Confirm you that with Xcode 7 and iOS 9 you can run your 8.0 target App !

**EXTRA** : **The Only Problem:**

There is only a small bug if you're using Parse.com, you can't retrive PFFiles. So in this case you need to redevelop your app in Target 9.0 to make it work

hope it helps